# How can one override a class method inside a module inside a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, omniauth, saml

I'm trying to add a rescue statement to an otherwise failing gem. The trouble is is that I'm not correctly overriding the original gem's method. How can I accomplish this?

**Original Gem**

```
module OmniAuth
  class Configuration
    include Singleton
      def add_camelization(name, camelized)
        self.camelizations[name.to_s] = camelized.to_s
      end
```

**initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
module OmniAuth
  class Configuration
    def add_camelization(name, camelized)
      begin
        self.camelizations[name.to_s] = camelized.to_s
      rescue
        puts "No camelization for #{camelized}"
      end
      # ^ This rescue statement is not being called to replace the original gem's method.
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Just curious, have you tried using alias_method_chain?

Comment: Just curious, why is this tagged "saml"?

Comment: This is being integrated into a saml strategy for omniauth.. So I threw the extra saml tag in there just case this might have been common for folks going down the same path..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
OmniAuth::Configuration.class_eval do
    def add_camelization(name, camelized)
        ...
    end
end
```